# What is considered a positive rate?

Tags: airliner, takeoff, boeing-747

I'm a beginner pilot, and i am trying to perfect my takeoff. What vertical speed is considered a positive rate in a Boeing 747?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: A positive rate is anything above 0.

Answer (score 3):

Positive rate is any vertical speed that you are climbing.  i.e. greater than zero.

You don't want to raise the gear too early in the takeoff.  If you did and settled back down on the runway you would damage and/or destroy the aircraft.  It's best to be climbing above 100 to 200 feet AGL before raising the gear.  Even at that altitude, if you experience a windshear/microburst you may find that you are skidding on the ground again.

The arguments for getting the gear up right away are about drag improving climb performance with the gear up.

The arguments for keeping the gear down for a short period of time include windshear/microburst or poor takeoff technique.  If the airplane touches down again, I would much rather be on the gear and use the shock struts to absorb some energy during the impact.

Comment: Another issue with raising gear early is that for some aircraft there is an increase in drag during the transition.  For example gear doors that are closed when the gear is down and up have to open during transition and thus increase drag.  Not something you would want as you leave the runway.